# who is in charge of sort data in MVP Structure, View , presenter or Model?

Tags: android, android-mvp

I want to sort My ArrayList which I got it from the model If I want to put a dropdown to sort my data in Activity to sort in Date or alphabet ...
I must send the request to the presenter to sort my data or Can I sort it in view model?

Should the Presenter sort the list of items or is that a task for the view?

Answer (score -1):

> The correct answer is (drum roll please) it depends. Are you using a
>   UI framework that supports sorting natively? Are you sorting over a
>   large sequence that would be best performed as a database operation?
>   Does your UI framework support sorting through the database (e.g.
>   IQueryable support in many .NET UI toolkits).
>
> There are multiple approaches to MVP. You have the Passive View in
>   which the Presenter has deep knowledge of the view via an Interface,
>   there's the supervising controller in which the presenter handles
>   complex view logic and the rest is left to the view (so again if your
>   view objects can handle sorting, let them do it if it's not an
>   expensive operation), finally is the Presentation Model which is
>   pretty much equivalent to MVVM in which the Presenter exposes behavior
>   as properties and the View reacts to those properties.

taken from [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/192047) credit to [Michael Brown](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/13181/michael-brown)

Comment: *let them do it if it's not an expensive operation* this is hardly an argument worth considering in MVP, where it is all about separating concerns. Same goes for *Does your UI framework support sorting through the database (e.g. IQueryable support in many .NET UI toolkits)* because if the view has any knowledge about data storage you're doing something wrong